# Correct information from php code is not being inserted into Sql db

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently trying to make my Login/registration form work correctly.The Login part works with out any issues, but when Register.html is submitted correctly. this is getting inserted into the table of the DB:

```
-- Table structure for table `userlogin`
--

CREATE TABLE `userlogin` (
  `userid` int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Username` text NOT NULL,
  `Password` text NOT NULL,
  `Email` text NOT NULL,
  `Phone Number` text NOT NULL,
  `Carrier` text NOT NULL,
  `Service Status` text NOT NULL,
  `Service Info` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2369 ;

INSERT INTO `userlogin` VALUES(2367, '123', '1', '111@gmail.com', '', 'Verizon', '', '');
```

Copied from the DB.
The last two columns are supposed to be blank, but the Phone Number column is not being filled out. Here is my Code. Why isn't my Phone number column being populated? Thank you in advanced for your help.

**Register.html**

```
<form action="Register_check.php" method="post">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="Username" />
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" size="30" name="Password" />
    <p>Re-type Password:</p>
    <input type="password" size="30" name="PasswordConfirm" />
    <p>Email Address:</p>
    <input type="email" size="30" name="Email" />
    <p>Mobile Phone Number:</p>
    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="Phone Number" />
    <p>Carrier:</p>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="Carrier" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>

    <p>Already have an account?<a href="Login.html">Login</a></p>
```

**Register_check.php**

```
<?php
include ("cn.php");


if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from userlogin WHERE Username='" . $_POST['Username'] . "'")) == 1){
echo "<font color='red'>Sorry, that username is already in use</font>";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['Username']) ==0){
   echo "<font color='red'>Please enter a desired user name!</font>";
}
else if($_POST['Password'] != $_POST['PasswordConfirm']){
   echo "<font color='red'>Oops! The two entered passwords don`t match!</font>";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['Password']) ==0){
   echo "<font color='red'>Please enter a password!</font>";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['Email']) ==0){
   echo "<font color='red'>Please enter your email address</font>!";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['Phone Number']) ==0){
   echo "<font color='red'>Please enter your Mobile phone number with out spaces,- or ()!</font>";
}
else if(strlen($_POST['Carrier']) ==0){
   echo "<font color='red'>Please enter your Mobile phone carrier!</font>";

}



else{
mysql_query("INSERT into userlogin VALUES('".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['Username']."','".$_POST['Password']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['Phone Number']."','".$_POST['Carrier']."','".$_POST['Service Status']."','".$_POST['Service Info']."')") or die(mysql_error());

}
?>

<form action="Register_check.php" method="post">
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="Username" />
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" size="30" name="Password" />
    <p>Re-type Password:</p>
    <input type="password" size="30" name="PasswordConfirm" />
    <p>Email Address:</p>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="Email" />
   <p>Mobile Phone Number:</p>
    <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="Phone Number" />
    <p>Carrier:</p>
    <input type="text" size="30" name="Carrier" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

Comment: Stop and restart with `mysqli` or `pdo`, `prepared statements` and `encrypted password`

Comment: Have you tried to debug `$_POST['Phone Number']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the Phone Number filed in your html "PhoneNumber" and in php to $_POST["PhoneNumber"]

Comment: @user3336116 : My pleasure.IF it worked for you then mark this post as answer.